# How to add data from database to text widgets?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I'm trying to create a database of references through SQlite3 and retrieve author, title, etc. to return each to the text widget when I click on a reference from the listbox. I don't know what is the best way to do the following:

1. Retrieve data from selection in listbox (done).
2. Add data to the SQlite3 database (done).
3. After selection on the listbox, select each item from a row (through the selected index for example) in SQlite3 database according to the selection.
4. Return each item to its specified text widget after.

[image: Image of the Program]

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
import numpy as np

root=Tk()
root.title("References Library")


#Add Listbox
lb1 = Listbox(root, width = 103, height = 50, selectmode=EXTENDED)
lb1.place(x=0, y=92)

#SQl DB
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('myreferences.db')
cobj = con.cursor()
cobj.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myreferences(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Title TEXT, Author TEXT, DateofPulishing TEXT, ISBN TEXT)")
con.commit()

#insert values
def insert_value(ID, Title, Author, DateofPulishing, ISBN):
    cobj.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO myreferences VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",(ID, Title, Author, DateofPulishing, ISBN))
    con.commit()
def delete_all():
    cobj.execute("DELETE FROM myreferences")
    con.commit()

#Text widgets
t1=Text(root,height = 1, width = 60)
t1.grid(row=0, column=1)
print(type(t1))
t2=Text(root,height = 1, width = 60)
t2.grid(row=1, column=1)

t3=Text(root,height = 1, width = 30)
t3.grid(row=0, column=3)

t4=Text(root,height = 1, width = 30)
t4.grid(row=1, column=3)

def open_popup():
    top= Toplevel(root)
    top.geometry("300x150")
    top.resizable(False, False)
    top.title("ERROR")
    l6=Label(top, text= "Please, Enter Missing Information!", font=('Times New Roman', '11', 'bold'))
    l6.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.3, anchor ='center')
    b9 = Button(top, text="OK", width=15, command=top.destroy)
    b9.place(relx=0.5, rely = 0.6, anchor = 'center')

def i():
    t1s=str(t1.get("1.0",'end-1c'))
    t2s=str(t2.get("1.0",'end-1c'))
    t3s=str(t3.get("1.0",'end-1c'))
    t4s=str(t4.get("1.0",'end-1c'))
    if not t1s and t2s and t3s and t4s:
        open_popup()
    else:
        cobj.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myreferences")
        nofrows=cobj.fetchone()
        IDa = nofrows[0]
        ID = int(IDa)+1
        con.commit()
        refs = str(ID) + ", " + t1s + ", " + t2s + ", " + t3s + ", " + t4s
        lb1.insert(END,refs)
        insert_value(ID,t1s,t2s,t3s,t4s)
        t1.delete("1.0",END)
        t2.delete("1.0",END)
        t3.delete("1.0",END)
        t4.delete("1.0",END)



#View All Refs:
def fetch_all():
    cobj.execute("SELECT * FROM myreferences")
    results = cobj.fetchall()
    con.commit()
    lb1.delete(0,END)
    lb1.insert(END,results)

def fetch_t1(cobj,ID):
    cobj.execute("SELECT Title FROM myreferences WHERE ID=?",(ID,))
    t1result = cobj.fetchall()

def fetch_t2(ID):
    cobj.execute("SELECT Author FROM myreferences WHERE ID=?",(ID,))
    t2result = cobj.fetchall()

def fetch_t3(ID):
    cobj.execute("SELECT DateofPulishing FROM myreferences WHERE ID=?",(ID,))
    t3result = cobj.fetchall()

def fetch_t4(ID):
    cobj.execute("SELECT ISBN FROM myreferences WHERE ID=?",(ID,))
    t4result = cobj.fetchall()

def update_item(t1, t2, t3, t4):
    cobj.execute("UPDATE myreferences SET ID=?, Title=?, Author=?, DateofPulishing=?, ISBN=?", (t1, t2, t3, t4))

count = 1

def firstclick():
    t_value = lb1.get(ANCHOR)
    ID_value = t_value[0]
    t1value = fetch_t1(cobj,ID_value)
    t2value = fetch_t2(cobj,ID_value)
    t3value = fetch_t3(cobj,ID_value)
    t4value = fetch_t4(cobj,ID_value)
    #t_value = lb1.get(ANCHOR)
    #y = t_value.split()
    t1.insert(END,t1value)
    t2.insert(END,t2value)
    t3.insert(END,t3value)
    t4.insert(END,t4value)
def secondclick():
    t1.delete(1.0,END)
    t2.delete(1.0,END)
    t3.delete(1.0,END)
    t4.delete(1.0,END)

    t1.insert(END,t1value)
    t2.insert(END,t2value)
    t3.insert(END,t3value)
    t4.insert(END,t4value)
def clicker(event):
    global count
    count +=1
    if count%1000 ==0:
        firstclick()
    else:
        secondclick()
lb1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", clicker)

#Add Buttons
b1 = Button(root, text="View All", width=32, command = lambda: fetch_all())
b1.grid(row=2, column =3)

b2 = Button(root, text="Search in References", width=32)
b2.grid(row=3, column =3)

b3 = Button(root, text="Add Entry", width=32, command = lambda: i())
b3.grid(row=4, column =3)

b4 = Button(root, text="Clear Entries", width=32,command= lambda: deleteentries())
b4.grid(row=5, column =3)

b5 = Button(root, text="Clear Refs", width=32,command= lambda: deleterefs())
b5.grid(row=6, column =3)

b6 = Button(root, text="Update Selected", width=32,command = lambda: ireplace())
b6.grid(row=7, column =3)

b7 = Button(root, text="Delete Selected Item", width=32, command= lambda: lb1.delete(ANCHOR))
b7.grid(row=8, column =3)
#Add Exit Command
b8 = Button(root, text="Close", width=32, command=root.destroy)
b8.grid(row=9, column =3)


#Keep the Program Running
root.mainloop()

cobj.close()
con.close()
```

Comment: In the clicker function change ==0 to !=0, else you won't get the firstclick function before count will be equal to 1000

Comment: I don't understand what is the purpose behind `firstclick()` and `secondclick()` if you just want to populate the selected record into those text boxes when a record in the listbox is selected?

Comment: dear acw1668, I guess you have a point, I could just add the delete functions before the insert functions and define only one click function. Is that what you meant?

Comment: dear Ze'ev, I actually found this code when I was searching for an issue that appeared, and it actually works fine as is. Is there another reason that it works this way? Would love to learn from you.

Comment: I'm surprised that it works fine as is, there are issues that suppose to generate errors like the calling to fetch_t2, fetch_t3, and fetch_t4 that expect 1 parameter but get 2 and none of those functions returns values. I was just suggesting your next step get the function triggered, and I was leaving it to you to investigate inside. @acw1668 point was that the functionality of that function is somewhat strange, as you bind select of one row to change the content of the entire Listbox upon exactly 1000 clicker counts.